# What permissions are required for the Entity Framework to generate a model from a database?

Tags: entity-framework, permissions, sqlanywhere, ef-database-first

I am connecting to a third party SQL Anywhere instance and having issues generating an Entity Data Model from an existing database.  The connection is working with a basic ODBC connection, but when generating a model I am met with a "Permission denied: you do not have permission to select from "sysuserperm"' error.  My question is what permission should I ask to be added to this account so I can generate the model?

The full error message is below:[image]

Comment: Have you had any update in your search?

Comment: @IronMan84 Not much.  Like you said, what I am trying to do might only be allowed for users with DBA permissions.  This is because the Sybase designed SQL Anywhere component for .Net was apparently designed to check for all permissions immediately instead of as the permissions are needed.  That makes setting up a connection with limited permissions as basically a read only data source nearly impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, from what I can find, only the DBA itself is allowed to access that table (and the third party that you're using will undoubtedly not want to make you a DBA...)

The link that I found about that is [right here](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.1/dbadmin/uinfo.html).